# how to install magento 2.3.1 page builder extension

Tags: magento2.3, page-builder

There is a core magento page builder extension in magento 2.3.1 how to install this extension ?
In my installation there is no such extension.I updated magento  2.2 to magento 2.3.1 maybe it is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pagebuilder is inbuilt in **Magento Commerce 2.3.1**. It is available for Magento Commerce only. To learn more about this please visit this link https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/